# Print out 26 bytes from an byte array

Tags: c++

`response` is defined as Byte Array. I know how to print out the full  response:

```
 printf("Response: %s", response);
```

Or for example only the penultimate byte:

```
 response[lenr - 2]
```

But how can i print out the response from the 1 to the 26 Byte? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you've tagged this C++, use [C++ I/O](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write):

```
std::cout.write(response, 26);
```

Comment: And from the `4` to the `26` byte for example?

Comment: @JohnSmith `std::cout.write(response + 3, 22)`. I may be off by one but you get the idea. See [these docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write).